# How to efficiently store a two-dimensional array with different File types in a Django Model (PostgresSQL)

Tags: python, arrays, django, postgresql, django-models

I will like to store in a Django model the variations on the price of some houses for a date.
For example:

```
House.objects.create(name='house1', prices=[
    ['27-12-2015', 200000],
    ['14-01-2016', 190000],
])
House.objects.create(name='house2', prices=[
    ['22-04-2015', 140000],
])
```

Because I'm using PostgreSQL I can use a two-dimensional array with [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield). But I think it can't contain different type of Fields (for example date and int).

I will also like to be efficient when doing queries to get the prices for all the houses between 2 dates.

So my question: which is the best approach for this problem?

Comment: From the example and demands you are giving, I don't see why a `Price` model with fields `date`, `amount`, `house` (simple foreign key) should not work fine. Your data is not really two-dimensional when in each row there's always a price and a date and nothing else. This yells record in a table with typed columns to me.

Comment: Thank you @schwobaseggl! I was afraid of getting to many records (but I guess there is never to many records ;))